# I don't want to type directly the key of application insight to register log

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, logging, azure-application-insights

I don't want to type the key of application insight in the Program.cs, Can I type it in some file of configurations or in another place? It's a ASP .Net Core

I want to include a register in application insights of my logs but with modifications. Now I have a register, but I am typing the key in the Program.cs and I have "a problem" when I change of environment. Do you know any way to type this key dynamicly on the Program.cs or can I do this declaration in another place of the program.

This is the Program.cs. It started with the Main and after it starts the BuildWebHost where I load the key of applications insights and it's what I want to change:

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
                logging.AddApplicationInsights("db0fe38d-c208-8ed7-23e4ef4479bb");

                // Optional: Apply filters to configure LogLevel Trace or above is sent to
                // ApplicationInsights for all categories.
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);

                // Additional filtering For category starting in "Microsoft",
                // only Warning or above will be sent to Application Insights.
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
        }).Build();
```

How I said, I would avoid to type key on the Program and I would like take this param from a config file or type this declaration in another place

Comment: it's a .net core web application?

Comment: @IvanYang Yes, it's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add UseApplicationInsights(), then remove the instrumentation key(assume the instrumentation key set in the appsettings.json).

Sample code as below, and works well at my side:

```
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseApplicationInsights()  // add this line of code, and it will auto-read ikey from appsettings.json.
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            //then you can remove instrumentation key from here.
            logging.AddApplicationInsights();
            logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);


            logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
        }).Build();
```

Comment: adding UseApplicationInsights() to just read ikey from appsettings.json has possibly unintended side effects, as this method enables Request/Dependency monitoring.

Comment: @cijothomas, could you please explain more about "this method enables Request/Dependency monitoring"? thanks. I thought app insights always monitor request/dependency.

Comment: UseApplicationInsights() extension method on IWebHostBuilder, enables entire application insights monitoring - requests/dependencies/counters etc. The AddApplicationInsights() extension method on loggingBuilder just enables ILogger log capture. If the intent is to capture ilogger logs only, then the answer below by @martinbrandl is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is an ASP.NET Core application, you can use the `ConfigureLogging` extension method that injects the **WebHostBuilderContext** to retrieve your configuration:

```
 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
                var appInsightKey =  hostingContext.Configuration["MyAppInsight"];
                logging.AddApplicationInsights(appInsightKey);

                // Optional: Apply filters to configure LogLevel Trace or above is sent to
                // ApplicationInsights for all categories.
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);

                // Additional filtering For category starting in "Microsoft",
                // only Warning or above will be sent to Application Insights.
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
        }).Build();
```

Comment: When I typed .ConfigureLogging I have a Error: Adds a delegate for configuring the provided ILoggingBuilder. Cannot resolve method ConfigureLogging

Comment: I probably missed the parentheses: `(hostingContext, logging)`. I updated my answer.